# How to save all worksheets in Excel workbook as one text file?

Tags: python, excel, vba, text

I have an Excell workbook with multiple worksheets. I want to export the text of all worksheets to one text file. I've seen multiple solutions (primarily using VBA - example below) to export each worksheet as its own text file, but have yet to find a solution to export all worksheets as one text file. Any ideas as to how to accomplish this using VBA (or perhaps Python)?

```
Sub ExportSheetsToText()
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xTextFile As String
For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    xWs.Copy
    xTextFile = CurDir & "\" & xWs.Name & ".txt"
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xTextFile, FileFormat:=xlText
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you generate those text files, you can easily merge many text files into one using the Windows `Command Prompt`. Suppose for instance that all your file name have some pattern in their names. i.e. `*.txt` but I recommend you give them some additional pattern in their name, such as temp_something.txt:

```
xTextFile = CurDir & "\temp_" & xWs.Name & ".txt"
```

Then you merge them into one text file ine the command prompt like this:

```
type temp_*.txt >> mergedFile.txt
```

or

```
copy temp_*.txt mergedFile.txt
```

If you want to fully automate the operation inside the VBA routine, you can integrate the command inside it, like so:

```
For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    xWs.Copy
    xTextFile = CurDir & "\temp_" & xWs.Name & ".txt"
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xTextFile, FileFormat:=xlText
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close
Next

Dim shl As Object: Set shl = CreateObject("WScript.shell")
shl.CurrentDirectory = CurDir
shl.Run "cmd /C copy temp_*.txt " & ThisWorkbook.name & ".txt" ' merge the temporary text files

shl.Run "cmd /C del temp_*.txt" ' clean up the temporary text files
```

At the end you get a text file with the same name of you workbook plus the extension `.txt`.

Comment: That's really helpful. Thanks very much for the thorough guidance. Cheers.